# Undo Redo Feature for Photo Editing App

Tags: ios, swift, undo-redo

I am Creating Photo Editing App in **IOS** **SWIFT3**, i need to implement Undo Redo Feature. I have Searched for NSUndoManager but i didn't get any idea about how can i Implement this. can anyone Help me with this?

Comment: What do you want to implement with Image editing? Are you looking for drawing or something else. By the way look at these links http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/

Comment: @Gagan_iOS  :) Thanks for Answer I will check about this and I am Looking for Photo Editing App with Filters, Text and Stickers.

Comment: Ok..Look at this example https://github.com/acerbetti/ACEDrawingView  Please add key 'Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description' in plist before running the code. It will serve all your purpose.

Comment: check this control - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kcolorpicker